# Is it possible to control window shadows individually?

Tags: qt, widget, ubuntu-unity

Is it possible to control the shadows/glow behind the widget window's outer border? It seems to be automatically applied to all the windows, but I'd need to disable it for some of my application's windows.

Below is an example of the shadow I wish to disable:

[image: An example of window shadow.]

Comment: i think the shaddow is added by the unity windowmanager (maybe)

Comment: @Zailborg That is true, but the question still stands: how does one turn it off per-window.

Comment: @Zailborg it is made by QT creator.